# determining llvm::ConstantInt type with big integers (or: what type is i501?)

Tags: c++, c++17, llvm, llvm-c++-api

In my llvm written compiler (using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)), I want to synthesize a function that has an integer argument.

- If that integer's bit width is less than 65, I want that argument's type to be `uint64_t`.
- Otherwise, I want that argument's type to be `uint64_t*`, or a `uint64_t` that holds an array's address.

In the synthetization of that function, the integer's value is given in an `llvm::APint`, which can hold big integers; I know that the type of such `llvm::APInt` value might be a `uint64_t` or a `uint64_t*`, and that depends on the size of the given value.

The thing is, that when passing a big integer (bit width of 501), I get the following error:

```
 i64  call void @myFunc(i501 -3041471953062192995039706191509879097447877415144190182463294413280942179769929755723507030244044466058102684219790242203873301936326800667497770127617)
Call parameter type does not match function signature!
```

The argument that I pass to the function while synthesizing it is:

```
llvm::ConstantInt::get(context, apint);
```

And the function's signature is:

```
void myFunc(uint64_t value)
```

To summarize - I don't understand what type i501 is, and I don't understand what type should myFunc expect to get in its argument.
Alternatively, other suggestions for passing such value are welcome :)

---

I've tried using other llvm types when synthesizing myFunc, such as:

- `llvm::ConstantArray`
- `llvm::GlobalVariable` that contains the `llvm::ConstantInt` as its initializer
- `llvm::GlobalVariable` that contains the `llvm::ConstantArray` as its initializer

Either way, I get the same error that indicates a difference between my argument type to the expected argument type, but either way I don't understand *what* is the expected type.

I have also tried changing the signature to

```
void myFunc(uint64_t* value)
```

But it didn't help as well.

Comment: `i501` maps to the C23 type `_BitInt(501)`

Comment: @Artyer Do I have a quick way to make it either `i64` or `i64*`?
Or, alternatively, do u know what would be the type of a `[2 x i64] [i64 0x2233445566778899, i64 0x11]` that is passed when using `llvm::ConstantArray`?